# Selecting text between two Word bookmarks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically (C#, Office 2010 project in Visual Studio) select text between two bookmarks excluding the bookmarks themselves.  I have a feeling this should be easy but my Googling skills are letting me down!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, easy enough!

```
object start = Globals.ThisDocument.bm1.Start + 1;
object end = Globals.ThisDocument.bm2.Start - 1;
Range r = Globals.ThisDocument.Range(ref start, ref end);
```

Comment: Actually I guess the first line should be `object start = Globals.ThisDocument.bm1.End + 1;` if you have text in them but my bookmarks are empty